# Capacitors discharging in series

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance

If you connect positive plate of a charged  capacitor to ground, it doesn't get discharged. Now consider $4$ capacitors of equal capacitance connected in series to a $10\, \mathrm{V}$ battery. Connect a wire joining the $3^{\mathrm{rd}}$ and $4^{\mathrm{th}}$ capacitor to the ground. You will notice that the positive plate of $4^{\mathrm{th}}$ capacitor gets discharged and the potential to the right side of positive plate becomes $7.5\, \mathrm{V}$ and potential to the left side of $4^{\mathrm{th}}$ capacitor becomes $-2.5\, \mathrm{V}$.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what your conceptual question is?

Comment: This was expounded upon in this [repeat question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63300/capacitor-charging-and-discharging-when-connected-to-the-ground/64015#64015). (For future reference, @Dr.Apoorva Kulkarni, you can edit your question and this will push it back onto the "new" page)